WPF TabControl loads multiple tabs but same content in all the tabs
<TabControl Name="tabSections" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local2:TestType}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local2:TestType}">
            <StackPanel>
                <local:MyUserControl x:Name="uc1" ItemSource="{Binding}" Loaded="UcLoaded">
                </local:MyUserControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>

Here MyUserControl contains a datagrid, that populates items from some property of TestType.
ItemSource for MyUserControl is a dependancy property, that holds the entore testtype object.
in code behind, I am adding a List to tabcontrol's ItemSource,
tabSections.ItemsSource = TestTypeList;//TestTypeList is List
with this, I get 2 tab heads(as the list contains 2 items),
but both the tab contains same content(1st content), with no value change.
if I bring my usercontrol to itemtemplate instead of content template, then both the tab shows correctly. but the UI does not look good, as the table(from usercontrol) comes into tab head.
The number of items in the TestTypeList is dynamic, so could not go with TabItem.
Please suggest, where I am doing wrong.

If you need help to debug your code then you must post a complete minimal example that we can review.

I would like to present a simple solution.
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
     <TabControl.Resources>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AccountViewModel}">
             <local:AccountUserControl/>
         </DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AddressViewModel}">
             <local:AddressUserControl/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </TabControl.Resources>
     <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
     <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ContentControl Content="{Binding }"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
 </TabControl>

The MainViewModel is
    public class MainViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
        List<ItemViewModel> _items = new List<ItemViewModel>();
        public List<ItemViewModel> Items 
        {
            get { return _items; } 
            set { _items = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items)); }
        }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Items= [new AddressViewModel(),new AccountViewModel()];
        }
 }

The ItemViewModel is :
public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    string _label = "";
    public string Label
    {
        get { return _label; }
        set {  _label = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Label)); } 
    }
}

The AccountViewModel is :
public class AccountViewModel : ItemViewModel
{
    string _AccountNumber = "";
    public string AccountNumber
    {
        get { return _AccountNumber; }
        set { _AccountNumber = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AccountNumber)); }
    }
    string _bank = "";
    public string Bank
    {
        get { return _bank; }
        set { _bank = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Bank)); }
    }
    public AccountViewModel()
    {
        Label = "Account";
        Bank = "People Bank";
        AccountNumber = "791800";
    }
            
}

The AddressViewModel is :
public class AddressViewModel : ItemViewModel
{
    string _address = "";
    public string Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set { _address = value;OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Address)); }
    }
    string _city = "";
    public string City
    {
        get { return _city; }
        set { _city = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(City)); }
    }

    public AddressViewModel()
    {
        Label = "Address";
        Address = "1349 BellField Way";
        City = "Belleview";
    }
}

The AccountUserControl is :
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountNumber}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bank}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

The AddressUserControl is :
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}"/>
    </StackPanel>   
</Grid>

